# series 0, 6, 13, 20, 27

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working with days of the week and need to generate a series thats $n*7-1$ except for where $n=1$ where it should be $0$.

So the series I'm after is $0,6,13,20,27$

I can't figure out a formula for this series though!

Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be $0,6,13,20,27$?

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't get (and probably don't really need) a single "formula". This will work in any document, or computer program, or spreadsheet:

$$f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
7n -1 &  n \ne 0 \\
0 & n= 0
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Kronecker delta](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta&ved=2ahUKEwjpxNCCw6PbAhWppFkKHU7QB2MQFjAAegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw3FpvjXy9hP_jGHeRxDy-ap):

$a_n=7n-1+\delta_{0,n}$

Note we start with $n=0$.